# Unable to update a joined recordset - MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

The following code gives me an error: "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only." I had an implicit `JOIN` but removed it and it still isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim mySQL As String
Dim rsSQL As String

rsSQL = "SELECT tblTable1.aaaID, tblTable1.bbbID, tblTable2.ccc, " & _
        "Sum(tblTable2.ddd) AS Name, tblTable1.eee, tblTable2.fff " & _
        "FROM (tblTable3 INNER JOIN tblTable1 ON tblTable3.aaaID = tblTable1.aaaID) " & _
        "INNER JOIN tblTable2 ON tblTable3.aaaID = tblTable2.aaaID " & _
        "GROUP BY tblTable1.aaaID, tblTable1.bbbID, tblTable2.ccc, tblTable1.eee, tblTable2.fff " & _
        "HAVING (((tblTable1.aaaID)=88) AND ((tblTable1.bbbID)=1) AND ((tblTable2.fff)=True));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(rsSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs!ccc = "xxx" Then               'This is a text value
           rs.Edit                           'Here is where the code fails
           rs!eee = eee + Name               '"eee" and "Name" are currency
           rs.Update
        Else
            rs.Edit                          'And here, too
            rs!eee = eee - Name
            rs.Update
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmForm1", acSaveYes
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your query the same, just change the update.
Instead of rs.ccc= do something like:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTable2 " _
       & "SET eee= (" & rs.eee + rs.name & ")" _
       & "WHERE PK= " & rs.pk & "

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you explain a little more? Do you mean replace the statements between `If` and `Else`?

Comment: You will be taking out `rs.edit...rs.update` sections and replacing it with this bit above.  It's a method to update the table that is different and unrelated to the other code (so it works, yay!).  You will want to turn off `SetWarnings` and turn it back on again after, to avoid dialog boxes.

Comment: Fantastic! I had to use one DLookup to populate `eee`. If there's a better way let me know. But it's working! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

A query built with `GROUP BY` must always be non-updateable.  You will need to change your approach.  Use queries outside of VBA to get a workable query started (because that allows for convenient testing).

Comment: I used the query builder to get the above query. So I know it works. What you said about `GROUP BY` makes sense. Would it be possible to get the field value from the `GROUP BY` and assign it to a variable and then add the variable to the field via a `DLookup`? (Still consider myself new to Access).

Comment: You are on the right trail.  But `DLookup()` doesn't apply.  Use (and accept) the answer from @yoelbenyossef.

Comment: (By "workable query" I only meant updateable.  Sorry for confusion.)